# Scaling to screen size in Outlook

Tags: outlook, html-email

Email isn’t scaling to screen size in outlook. Testing with email on acid and it’s working for other clients, can anyone give me advice?

Code is below. Would appreciate some advice on what needs fixing as this is my first attempt to code an email.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>See what our customers say</title>
 <style type="text/css">

 </style>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
     xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">

<head>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
  <o:AllowPNG/>
  <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
 </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ebebeb" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; border-collapse: collapse !important; margin: 0; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 0;">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td width="640">
   <table align="center" border="0" cass="container" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" class="logo" valign="top" width="100%" height="auto" align="center" style="width: 100%; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;" pardot-data=""><a href="#"><img alt="Pay4Later" border="0" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-08-18/23htmw/73452/32364/testimonials.jpg" style="display: block; width: 100%;" width="100%"></a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" class="headline" style="padding: 15px 20px 5px 30px; border: 0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; width: 100%;" valign="top">
      <h1 style="margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px; font-weight: normal; font-size: 32px; line-height: 32px; color: #414141;">DON'T JUST TAKE<br>
      OUR WORD FOR IT</h1>

      <p><i>See what our customers say</i></p>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="left" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" class="content" style="padding: 0px 60px; border: 0px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; color: rgb(65, 65, 65); width: 100%; background-color: rgb(249, 246, 242); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;" valign="top" pardot-data="">There’s no doubt that offering finance to your customers is a guaranteed way to dramatically increase your sales. Pay4Later takes digital lending further by giving you market leading acceptance rates and maximising order values, but don’t just take our word for it. See what our customers say...</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" pardot-data="" style="padding: 20px 0px; background-color: rgb(249, 246, 242); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; width: 100%;" width="100%" class=""><img src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-08-27/25s4sf/73452/34320/line_half.png"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" height="130" style="padding: 0 40px;" width="130" class=""><img height="130" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-08-27/25s4y5/73452/34330/cotswold.png" style="width: 130px; height: 130px;" width="130"></td>
         <td bgcolor="#f9f6f2" class="content" style="border: 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height:22px; color: #414141; padding-right: 50px;">“We trust Pay4Later with our customers, as Pay4Later’s performance with them reflects on our brand, too. We find that customers get great care from the company when needed, and we couldn’t be happier."</td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" style="padding: 20px 0;" width="100%" class=""><img src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-08-27/25s4sf/73452/34320/line_half.png"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td bgcolor="#f9f6f2" class="content" style="border: 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height:22px; color: #414141; padding-left: 50px;">“We trust Pay4Later with our customers, as Pay4Later’s performance with them reflects on our brand, too. We find that customers get great care from the company when needed, and we couldn’t be happier."</td>
         <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" height="130" style="padding: 0 40px;" width="130" class=""><img height="130" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-09-02/26hr5h/73452/35206/mango.png" style="width: 130px; height: 130px;" width="130"></td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" style="padding: 20px 0;" width="100%" class=""><img src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-08-27/25s4sf/73452/34320/line_half.png"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" height="130" style="padding: 0 40px;" width="130" class=""><img height="130" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-08-27/25s4yt/73452/34340/oak_furniture.png" style="width: 130px; height: 130px;" width="130"></td>
         <td bgcolor="#f9f6f2" class="content" style="border: 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height:22px; color: #414141; padding-right: 50px;">“We trust Pay4Later with our customers, as Pay4Later’s performance with them reflects on our brand, too. We find that customers get great care from the company when needed, and we couldn’t be happier."</td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" style="padding: 20px 0;" width="100%" class=""><img src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-08-27/25s4sf/73452/34320/line_half.png"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td bgcolor="#f9f6f2" class="content" style="border: 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height:22px; color: #414141; padding-left: 50px;">“We trust Pay4Later with our customers, as Pay4Later’s performance with them reflects on our brand, too. We find that customers get great care from the company when needed, and we couldn’t be happier."</td>
         <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" height="130" style="padding: 0 40px;" width="130" class=""><img height="130" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-08-27/25s4yf/73452/34336/gymkit_uk.jpg" style="width: 130px; height: 130px;" width="130"></td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" style="padding: 20px 0;" width="100%" class=""><img height="3" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-08-27/25s4sf/73452/34320/line_half.png" style="width: 544px; height: 3px;" width="544"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" height="130" style="padding: 0 40px;" width="130" class=""><img height="130" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-08-27/25s4yp/73452/34338/wongs.png" style="width: 130px; height: 130px;" width="130"></td>
         <td bgcolor="#f9f6f2" class="content" style="border: 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height:22px; color: #414141; padding-right: 50px;">“We trust Pay4Later with our customers, as Pay4Later’s performance with them reflects on our brand, too. We find that customers get great care from the company when needed, and we couldn’t be happier."</td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" style="padding: 20px 0;" width="100%" class=""><img src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-08-27/25s4sf/73452/34320/line_half.png"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td bgcolor="#f9f6f2" class="content" style="border: 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height:22px; color: #414141; padding-left: 50px;">“We trust Pay4Later with our customers, as Pay4Later’s performance with them reflects on our brand, too. We find that customers get great care from the company when needed, and we couldn’t be happier."</td>
         <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" height="130" style="padding: 0 40px;" width="130" class=""><img height="130" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-09-07/26x153/73452/35954/home_leisure.png" style="width: 130px; height: 130px;" width="130"></td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" style="padding: 20px 0;" width="100%" class=""><img src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-08-27/25s4sf/73452/34320/line_half.png"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" style="padding-top: 30px;" width="640">
      <table align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" style="border:2px solid #000000;" width="200">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td align="center" style="padding:10px 6px;" class=""><a href="https://www.example.com" style="color:#000000;font-size:14px;font-weight:700;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;"><span style="font-family: 'Roboto', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;">SIGNUP NOW</span> </a></td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="left" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" class="content" style="padding: 50px 100px 0px 100px; border: 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height:22px; color: #414141;" valign="top">To learn more about how your business can benefit from Pay4Later’s finance solutions you can reply to this email&nbsp;or call us on&nbsp;0800 021 7150.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="left" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" class="content" style="padding: 50px 100px 0px 100px; border: 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height:8px; color: #414141;" valign="top">
      <p><span>Kind Regards,</span></p>

      <p><span>The Pay4Later Team</span></p>

      <p><span>0800 021 7150</span></p>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td width="640">
      <table align="center" bgcolor="#0092ce" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td align="left" bgcolor="#0092ce" class="content" style="padding: 30px 100px 10px 100px; border: 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height:8px; color: #ffffff;" valign="top" width="100%">
         <p><span>Pay4Later Ltd</span></p>

         <p><span>33 St Mary Axe</span></p>

         <p><span>London, EC3A 8AG</span></p>
         </td>
         <td class=""><a href="https://www.example.com" style="text-decoration:none"><img alt="Twitter" border="0" height="30" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-09-02/26hq9t/73452/35156/twitter.png" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" title="Twitter" width="30"> </a></td>
         <td class=""><a href="https://www.example.com" style="text-decoration:none"><img alt="Google" border="0" height="30" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-09-02/26hqr7/73452/35184/linkedIn.png" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; padding-left: 15px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" title="Google" width="30"> </a></td>
         <td class=""><a href="https://www.example.com" style="text-decoration:none"><img alt="RSS" border="0" height="30" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-09-02/26hqrp/73452/35186/mail.png" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 7px; padding-right: 20px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" title="RSS" width="30"> </a></td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#ebebeb" class="content" style="padding: 10px 100px 0px 100px; border: 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height:22px; color: #414141;" valign="top">If you don't want to receive more mails, just <a href="%%unsubscribe%%" style="color:#a2a2a2;text-decoration:underline;">click here</a></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<div style="display:none; white-space:nowrap; font:15px courier; color:#ffffff;">
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "scale to screen" you mean that the image is so much larger in all Outlook, this is because Outlook tends to size images based on the actual size of the hosted image, not your declarations - especially when used as percentages. Your best bet is to resize the hosted image to 640px wide and Outlook should behave properly.

There are many different theories on getting around this, but the only definitive way I have found is to make Outlook behave is to resize the images to the scale you want them to be.

Answer (score 0):

HTML attributes (as in, width="640") can be used to resize images in Outlook. If width is defined, height will be rescaled accordingly. This works in all Outlook versions. However, the image will not be fluid (100% width) with this fix in place. It doesn't look like that's an issue for your email, as it doesn't contain any responsive code. If you use media queries, a style with !important should be able to overwrite this width.

Here is a test showing how this will look: https://www.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/display/summary/r9Sdqkr0J2kICtkrwc0RUkioQ0uX2yID1BEMvfLUEUczL/shared

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>See what our customers say</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>

<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
  <o:AllowPNG/>
  <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
 </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml><![endif]-->

</head>
<body bgcolor="#ebebeb" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; border-collapse: collapse !important; margin: 0; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 0;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="640">
            <table align="center" border="0" class="container" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" class="logo" valign="top" width="100%" height="auto" align="center" style="width: 100%; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;" pardot-data=""><a href="#">
                            <img alt="Pay4Later" border="0" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-08-18/23htmw/73452/32364/testimonials.jpg" style="display: block; width: 640px;" width="640">
                        </a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" class="headline" style="padding: 15px 20px 5px 30px; border: 0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; width: 100%;" valign="top">
                        <h1 style="margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px; font-weight: normal; font-size: 32px; line-height: 32px; color: #414141;">DON'T JUST TAKE<br>
                        OUR WORD FOR IT</h1>

                        <p><i>See what our customers say</i></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" class="content" style="padding: 0px 60px; border: 0px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; color: rgb(65, 65, 65); width: 100%; background-color: rgb(249, 246, 242); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;" valign="top" pardot-data="">There’s no doubt that offering finance to your customers is a guaranteed way to dramatically increase your sales. Pay4Later takes digital lending further by giving you market leading acceptance rates and maximising order values, but don’t just take our word for it. See what our customers say...</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" pardot-data="" style="padding: 20px 0px; background-color: rgb(249, 246, 242); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; width: 100%;" width="100%" class=""><img src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-08-27/25s4sf/73452/34320/line_half.png"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" height="130" style="padding: 0 40px;" width="130" class=""><img height="130" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-08-27/25s4y5/73452/34330/cotswold.png" style="width: 130px; height: 130px;" width="130"></td>
                                    <td bgcolor="#f9f6f2" class="content" style="border: 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height:22px; color: #414141; padding-right: 50px;">“We trust Pay4Later with our customers, as Pay4Later’s performance with them reflects on our brand, too. We find that customers get great care from the company when needed, and we couldn’t be happier."</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" style="padding: 20px 0;" width="100%" class=""><img src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-08-27/25s4sf/73452/34320/line_half.png"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td bgcolor="#f9f6f2" class="content" style="border: 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height:22px; color: #414141; padding-left: 50px;">“We trust Pay4Later with our customers, as Pay4Later’s performance with them reflects on our brand, too. We find that customers get great care from the company when needed, and we couldn’t be happier."</td>
                                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" height="130" style="padding: 0 40px;" width="130" class=""><img height="130" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-09-02/26hr5h/73452/35206/mango.png" style="width: 130px; height: 130px;" width="130"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" style="padding: 20px 0;" width="100%" class=""><img src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-08-27/25s4sf/73452/34320/line_half.png"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" height="130" style="padding: 0 40px;" width="130" class=""><img height="130" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-08-27/25s4yt/73452/34340/oak_furniture.png" style="width: 130px; height: 130px;" width="130"></td>
                                    <td bgcolor="#f9f6f2" class="content" style="border: 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height:22px; color: #414141; padding-right: 50px;">“We trust Pay4Later with our customers, as Pay4Later’s performance with them reflects on our brand, too. We find that customers get great care from the company when needed, and we couldn’t be happier."</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" style="padding: 20px 0;" width="100%" class=""><img src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-08-27/25s4sf/73452/34320/line_half.png"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td bgcolor="#f9f6f2" class="content" style="border: 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height:22px; color: #414141; padding-left: 50px;">“We trust Pay4Later with our customers, as Pay4Later’s performance with them reflects on our brand, too. We find that customers get great care from the company when needed, and we couldn’t be happier."</td>
                                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" height="130" style="padding: 0 40px;" width="130" class=""><img height="130" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-08-27/25s4yf/73452/34336/gymkit_uk.jpg" style="width: 130px; height: 130px;" width="130"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" style="padding: 20px 0;" width="100%" class=""><img height="3" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-08-27/25s4sf/73452/34320/line_half.png" style="width: 544px; height: 3px;" width="544"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" height="130" style="padding: 0 40px;" width="130" class=""><img height="130" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-08-27/25s4yp/73452/34338/wongs.png" style="width: 130px; height: 130px;" width="130"></td>
                                    <td bgcolor="#f9f6f2" class="content" style="border: 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height:22px; color: #414141; padding-right: 50px;">“We trust Pay4Later with our customers, as Pay4Later’s performance with them reflects on our brand, too. We find that customers get great care from the company when needed, and we couldn’t be happier."</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" style="padding: 20px 0;" width="100%" class=""><img src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-08-27/25s4sf/73452/34320/line_half.png"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td bgcolor="#f9f6f2" class="content" style="border: 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height:22px; color: #414141; padding-left: 50px;">“We trust Pay4Later with our customers, as Pay4Later’s performance with them reflects on our brand, too. We find that customers get great care from the company when needed, and we couldn’t be happier."</td>
                                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" height="130" style="padding: 0 40px;" width="130" class=""><img height="130" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-09-07/26x153/73452/35954/home_leisure.png" style="width: 130px; height: 130px;" width="130"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" style="padding: 20px 0;" width="100%" class=""><img src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-08-27/25s4sf/73452/34320/line_half.png"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" style="padding-top: 30px;" width="640">
                        <table align="center" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" style="border:2px solid #000000;" width="200">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="padding:10px 6px;" class=""><a href="https://www.example.com" style="color:#000000;font-size:14px;font-weight:700;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;"><span style="font-family: 'Roboto', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;">SIGNUP NOW</span> </a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" class="content" style="padding: 50px 100px 0px 100px; border: 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height:22px; color: #414141;" valign="top">To learn more about how your business can benefit from Pay4Later’s finance solutions you can reply to this email&nbsp;or call us on&nbsp;0800 021 7150.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" bgcolor="#f9f6f2" class="content" style="padding: 50px 100px 0px 100px; border: 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height:8px; color: #414141;" valign="top">
                        <p><span>Kind Regards,</span></p>

                        <p><span>The Pay4Later Team</span></p>

                        <p><span>0800 021 7150</span></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="640">
                        <table align="center" bgcolor="#0092ce" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="left" bgcolor="#0092ce" class="content" style="padding: 30px 100px 10px 100px; border: 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height:8px; color: #ffffff;" valign="top" width="100%">
                                    <p><span>Pay4Later Ltd</span></p>

                                    <p><span>33 St Mary Axe</span></p>

                                    <p><span>London, EC3A 8AG</span></p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class=""><a href="https://www.example.com" style="text-decoration:none"><img alt="Twitter" border="0" height="30" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-09-02/26hq9t/73452/35156/twitter.png" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" title="Twitter" width="30"> </a></td>
                                    <td class=""><a href="https://www.example.com" style="text-decoration:none"><img alt="Google" border="0" height="30" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-09-02/26hqr7/73452/35184/linkedIn.png" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; padding-left: 15px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" title="Google" width="30"> </a></td>
                                    <td class=""><a href="https://www.example.com" style="text-decoration:none"><img alt="RSS" border="0" height="30" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/73452/2015-09-02/26hqrp/73452/35186/mail.png" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 7px; padding-right: 20px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" title="RSS" width="30"> </a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" bgcolor="#ebebeb" class="content" style="padding: 10px 100px 0px 100px; border: 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height:22px; color: #414141;" valign="top">If you don't want to receive more mails, just <a href="%%unsubscribe%%" style="color:#a2a2a2;text-decoration:underline;">click here</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div style="display:none; white-space:nowrap; font:15px courier; color:#ffffff;">
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there really isn't any kind of scaling for emails in outlook, they take a fixed size and then keep it that way. As has been mentioned you can specify widths in attributes, and this will force that content to the size you specify.

One fairly popular way is starting with a fixed size and then setting elements of the email to have a % max width; this means that outlook will be happy with the fixed widths, and clients which support % widths will also be able to display yor content in a responsive way.